# What is the particular solution for the PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDE:
$$
u_t(x,t) = ku_{xx}(x,t)+F(x,t), 
$$
$$
u(0,t)=0, \hspace{0.2cm} u(L,t)=0
$$
$$
u(x,0)=\varphi(x)
$$
With $F(x,t)$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ continuous. And $F(0,t)=F(L,t)=0, \forall t>0$.

I know that the solution of the homogeneous system is:
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n(t)\phi_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_ne^{k\lambda_nt}\phi_n(x)
$$
With
$$
\lambda_n=-\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2, \hspace{0.2cm} \phi_n(x)=\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}
$$
$$
c_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}\varphi(x)\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}dx
$$

Now I am looking for the particular solution $v(x,t)$ for the inhomogeneous system that will allow me to find the  general solution:
$$
v_t(x,t)=kv_{xx}(x,t)+F(x,t),\hspace{0.22cm} (3)
$$
$$
v(0,t)=0, \hspace{0.2cm} v(L,t)=0 
$$
$$
v(x,0)=0
$$

Comment: You might be interested in looking up *Duhamel's principle*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a real benefit of doing it in 2 seperate steps:

You start exactly the way you did with the following Ansatz which satisfies the boundary conditions:

$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n(t)\phi_n(x) \mbox{ , with }
\phi_n(x)=\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}
$$
Now you plug it into the equation and get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c'_n(t)\phi_n(x)=-k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n(t)\phi_n(x)\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2+F(t,x)\\
\Rightarrow \int_0^L\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c'_n(t)\phi_n(x)\phi_j(x)dx=-\int_0^Lk\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n(t)\phi_n(x)\phi_j(x)\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2dx+\int_0^LF(t,x)\phi_j(x)dx\\
$$
Where I have multiplied with $\phi_j(x)$ and integrated over the domain. Now since the $\phi_n$ are orthogonal we end up with
$$
\frac{L}{2}c'_j(t)=-kc_j(t)\frac{j^2\pi^2}{2L}+\int_0^LF(t,x)\phi_j(x)dx
$$
Now you have to solve this ODE for the $c_j$'s and finally plug it in the inital condition.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was that easy. But I need the particular solution because I want to express the general solution in $u(x,t)=v(x,t)+w(x,t)$